# Bluetooth connection status

Tags: bluetooth, connection, status

Is there is any method to check the status of bluetooth connection whether it is connected or not to mobile from pc j2se program.
I am using bluecove2.1.1 for bluetooth connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to check if it is closed or opened, you could use the *isClosed* method from *BluetoothConnectionAccessAdapter*, which returns a boolean value.

See documentation for more info: http://bluecove.org/bluecove/apidocs/index.html.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply, i also want to check that after connection between pc and mobile is there is any method to check that mobile is out of bluetooth range and pc program is in listening state to search for mobile again,please help me regarding this issue

Comment: This explains pretty much everything: [blog link here](http://www.aviyehuda.com/2010/01/connecting-to-bluetooth-devices-with-java). Every time you want to search for devices you should do an inquiry and catch it in the deviceDiscoveder method of the listener. To avoid finding the same devices you should keep a list somewhere with the current devices.

Comment: I really appreciated your guide, i have all ready done the work which is in the link you send me, my program sending a message to mobile without any client application on mobile side, now i want to check that my programe check the bluetooth connection status after connected to mobile when mobile bluetooths off or mobile is out of range of pc bluetooth,plz help